# How to use the for loop else statement in python 3 when you don't want to break?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Is this the best way to execute the following code or is there a way to do it with an else statement after the for loop?

```
moved = False
for action in actions:
    if action.type == KEY:
        moved = True
        if action.key == UP:
            move_forward()
        update_all()
if not moved:
    update_all()
```

Comment: _Is this the best way to execute the following code_ Is there something wrong with it ?

Comment: You can't use `else:` for this. `else` is specifically about `break`. It removes the need for a "found" flag in _many_ cases, but not in _every possible_ case, and your case is one that it doesn't help.

Comment: That being said, do you really need an `update_all` after each `KEY`? And, if so, do you really need to skip the final `update_all` if you did one or more earlier? Because obviously you could make this a lot simpler if either of those requirements is unnecessary.

Comment: @DusanGligoric With the current lack of context, no, it should absolutely NOT be on Code Review. Please take a look at their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

For that specific piece of code you could reduce to:

```
for action in actions:
    if action.type == KEY and action.key == UP:
        move_forward()
update_all()
```

Since you're always updating, even if your action is not of type KEY.

Answer (score 0):

If there's any reason to update all, do it at the end after the for each loop

```
moved = False
for action in actions:
    if (action.type == KEY and action.key == UP):
        moved = True
        move_forward()
update_all()
```